# What are the values for JOptionPane showConfirmDialog options?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

If I have a question like

```
someMethod(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you enrolled in a University?"));
```

and I want to pass the answer "yes" or "no" to a method...what parameter should that method be accepting?
I thought it would be boolean (yes is true, no is false) but I guess I was wrong and a bit of amateur thinking.
Do the yes and no answers have a int value then?

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: that's a question most easily answered by reading the api doc - so always it handy :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: This is what I thought too. But my API says: "Returns: an integer indicating the option selected by the user"

Answer (score 9):

[JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) returns an `int` value which is interpretted into predefined values such as `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` and 
`JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`. If you want to use the result directly you would have to have a method such as:

```
void someMethod(int dialogResult)
```

Answer (score 8):

It will return an `int` which represents which button was pressed. Run the code without the method call, and see what order the buttons are in ('Yes No Cancel' or whatever). If you hit yes in that example, it'd return 0, No would return 1, and Cancel 2 (closing the dialog returns -1). It's simply returns the index starting from 0.

See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) for more info.