# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog returns int 01 instead of String YN

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

This is the result of my program:

[image]

but what I am trying to do is make the results for the room type be G, P, and L and, Y and N for the yes or no questions instead of 0123.

Below is the code I've been doing, could you tell me where I have done wrong and what should I do?

```
    public static void  main(String[] args){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Easy Living Resort Hotel.\n" + "----------------------------------------------------\n" + 
        "    Room Type             Daily Rate \n" + "~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ~~~~~~~~~~\n" + "G - Garden View        Php 125.00\n" + 
        "P - Pool View             Php 145.00\n" + "L - Lake View            Php 180.00\n");

      
      /*String[] options = new String[] {"G", "P", "L"};
      int answer1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "G - Garden View\n" + "P - Pool View\n" + "L - Lake View\n", "Please select room type:",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[0]);*/
      
      String answer2;
      int answer1;
      int answer3;
      int answer4;
      
      String[] options = new String[] {"G", "P", "L"};
      answer1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "G - Garden View\n" + "P - Pool View\n" + "L - Lake View\n", "Please select room type:",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[0]);
      
      answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Number of days staying: ");
      answer3 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want use a Refrigerator for Php 2.50 each day.");
      answer4 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to avail an extra bed for Php 15.00.");
      
      String output1 = String.format("Welcome to Easy Living Resort Hotel.\n");
      String output2 = String.format("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      String output3 = String.format("\n    Room Type             Daily Rate \n");
      String output4 = String.format("~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ~~~~~~~~~~\n");
      String output5 = String.format("G - Garden View        Php 125.00\n");
      String output6 = String.format("P - Pool View             Php 145.00\n");
      String output7 = String.format("L - Lake View            Php 180.00\n");
      String output8 = String.format("Please select room type: " + answer1);
      String output9 = String.format("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n");
      String output10 = String.format("Number of days staying: " + answer2 + "\n");
      String output11 = String.format("Refrigerator in the room? (Y/N): " + answer3 +"\n");
      String output12 = String.format("Extra bed in the room? (Y/N): " + answer4 + "\n");
      String output13 = String.format("-----------------------------------------------------------\n");      
      
      
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output1 + output2 + output3 + output4 + output5 + output6 + output7 + output8 + output9 + output10 + output11 + output12 + output13);
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider writing a proper [Swing application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) rather than a series of `JOptionPane`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[] outpyn = new String[] {"x","Y","N","N/A"};
  String output11 = String.format("Refrigerator in the room? (Y/N): " + outpyn[answer3+1] +"\n");
  String output12 = String.format("Extra bed in the room? (Y/N): " + outpyn[answer4+1] + "\n");
```

This is result after change:
[image]

This Stack Overflow question contains partly solution:
[What are the values for JOptionPane showConfirmDialog options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438838/what-are-the-values-for-joptionpane-showconfirmdialog-options/12438851)